# Why doesn't SendGrid need DNS modifications

Tags: email, dns, smtp, sendgrid

I was looking into SendGrid and came upon this interesting forum post saying you don't have to make DNS mods to ensure deliverability:
http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/why_dont_i_need_an_spf_record_or_other_dns_mods

> Our Free accounts do not require any DNS changes because we set the return path header, SPF, and DomainKeys headers to point to SendGrid's SPF and DomainKeys.

My question is if this approach is reliable and the experience from our clients' side isn't affected. Also, what's stopping anyone from sending emails on behalf of our domain if SendGrid automatically makes them seem reliable?

Thanks,
Vilem

Comment: Well, that at least saves me one SPF DNS-lookup. Thanks to Office365 using 9 those are at a premium.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is that on the accounts that don't have a dedicated IP address (including the free account) the SPF and DKIM signatures point back to SendGrid controlled domains rather than client controlled domains. It is definitely reliable and works, but some email clients (notably gmail) will display a "via sendgrid.info" message.

[image: example]

Comment: It seems to be possible to avoid this even with a free account. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36431237/560114.